# Show and Tabs in Razor using IF/ELSE

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have some tabs:

```
    <div class="page-tabs">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class='@(ViewBag.IsAmendment == "0" ? "active" : "")'>
            <a href='@Url.Action("ReviewDetails", "SongsManagement")' title="Original">Original</a>
        </li>
        @if (!Model.OriginalWork.IsNew)
    {
        <li class='@(ViewBag.IsAmendment == "1" ? "active" : "")'>
            <a href='@Url.Action("ReviewDetails", "SongsManagement",new {isAmendment=1} )' title="Amendment">Active Amendment</a>
        </li>
}
    </ul>
</div>
```

Currently the Original is shown, then if the IsNew is changed in the DB the Active is shown. Is there a way I can hide the Original tab. Then show it along with the Original when there is an Active Amendment?

Comment: If this is written in partial view and you are refreshing it then adding this in `else` block will help.

Comment: So just do an `else` block then and remove the first option?

Comment: yes, add your `<li>...Original</li>` to else block.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tabs in Razor only one tab is active](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51743347/tabs-in-razor-only-one-tab-is-active)

Comment: Please don't ask the same question multiple times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="page-tabs">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    @if (!Model.OriginalWork.IsNew)
    {
        if(ViewBag.IsAmendment == "1")
        {
            <li>
                <a href='@Url.Action("ReviewDetails", "SongsManagement")' title="Original">Original</a>
            </li>
        }
        <li class='@(ViewBag.IsAmendment == "1" ? "active" : "")'>
            <a href='@Url.Action("ReviewDetails", "SongsManagement",new {isAmendment=1} )' title="Amendment">Active Amendment</a>
        </li>
    }
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: That is still showing the Original tab, is there a way to remove it?

Comment: what do you mean by show actually? do you mean render, or do you mean making active?

Comment: when Model.OriginalWork.IsNew equals true, it will show original tab, otherwise Amendment tab is shown.

Comment: So currently the page has the Original tab showing. I need to hide that and only have it when the Amendment is true to show the Original and Amendment.

Comment: what do you mean by isnew is changed in db? Does changing mean setting it to true or false?

Comment: It is changed in the db. to true or false.

Comment: Is there a reason why the `active` class is only applying to the `Amendment` Tab and not the original when I click on it?