# Tabs in Razor only one tab is active

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor, bootstrap-tabs

I have the following tabs in my Razor:

```
<div class="page-tabs">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    @if (!Model.OriginalWork.IsNew)
    {

        <li class='@(ViewBag.IsAmendment == "0" ? "active" : "")'>
        <a href='@Url.Action("ReviewDetails", "SongsManagement", new { isAmendment = 0 }))' title="Original">Original</a>
    </li>
        <li class='@(ViewBag.IsAmendment == "1" ? "active" : "")'>
            <a href='@Url.Action("ReviewDetails", "SongsManagement", new { isAmendment = 1 })' title="Amendment">Active Amendment</a>
    </li>
    }
</ul>
```

Only the second tab is showing as active when I click on it. When I click on the original its not changing?

Comment: Razor doesn't have tabs. I'm guessing your using some kind of javascript library like bootstrap? Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/) of your problem

Comment: @Liam its using Boostrap. But that is my complete code, as I am using a partial.

Comment: Ok, next time, please add the correct tags. This still isn't a MCVE IMO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In first tab there is an extra parenthesis

```
<div class="page-tabs">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
@if (!Model.OriginalWork.IsNew)
{

    <li class='@(ViewBag.IsAmendment == "0" ? "active" : "")'>
    <a href='@Url.Action("ReviewDetails", "SongsManagement", new { isAmendment = 0 
  })' title="Original">Original</a>
</li>
    <li class='@(ViewBag.IsAmendment == "1" ? "active" : "")'>
        <a href='@Url.Action("ReviewDetails", "SongsManagement", new { isAmendment = 1 })' title="Amendment">Active Amendment</a>
</li>
}
 </ul>
```